# sort a QAbstractListModel from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I am a beginner in python and qt. I need to sort QAbstractList created in python by one attribute of list.I used sorted() method .But when i run the code python stops working.can u help.From Qml I called the slot sortData() .sortData() function is not correct i think
my code is

model2.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel

class PersonModel(QAbstractListModel):

    Name = Qt.UserRole + 1
    value1 = Qt.UserRole + 2
    value2 = Qt.UserRole + 3
    value3 = Qt.UserRole + 4
    value4 = Qt.UserRole + 5

    personChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.persons = [
            {'name': 'item1', 'value1': 10.66, 'value2':10.78, 'value3':10.94, 'value4':10.90},
            {'name': 'item1', 'value1': 10.56, 'value2':10.78, 'value3':10.34, 'value4':10.90},
            {'name': 'item2', 'value1': 10.66, 'value2':10.88, 'value3':10.44, 'value4':10.30}
        ]
        self.i=0
        print(self.persons)

    def data(self, QModelIndex, role):
        row = QModelIndex.row()
        if role == self.Name:
            return self.persons[row]['name']
        if role == self.value1:
            return self.persons[row]['value1']
        if role == self.value2:
            return self.persons[row]['value2']
        if role == self.value3:
            return self.persons[row]['value3']
        if role == self.value4:
            return self.persons[row]['value4']


    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.persons)

    def roleNames(self):
        return {
            Qt.UserRole + 1: b'name',
            Qt.UserRole + 2: b'value1',
            Qt.UserRole + 3: b'value2',
            Qt.UserRole + 4: b'value3',
            Qt.UserRole + 5: b'value4'
        }

    @pyqtSlot()
    def addData(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.persons = self.persons.append({'name': 'peter', 'value1': 22, 'value2':30, 'value3':40, 'value4':50})
        self.endResetModel()
        print(self.persons)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def editData(self):
        print(self.model.persons)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def sortData(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.persons = sorted(self.persons, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
        sorted(self.persons)
        #sorted_x = sorted(self._persons, key=lambda role: self.value1)
        #print(sorted_x)
        #self.persons.sort(2, key=Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.endResetModel()
        print(self.persons)
```

Hello.py

```
import sys, model2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel

from os import path
import PyQt5
import sys, model2

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import qmlRegisterType, QQmlComponent, QQmlEngine, QQmlListProperty
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, pyqtSignal,pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlListProperty

import sys, model2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
#import QSortFilterProxyModel

import imageResources
import fontResources

class MainWindow(QQuickView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.model = model2.PersonModel()
        self.proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel();
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('PersonModel', self.model)
        self.rootContext().setContextProperty('MainWindow', self)
        self.proxyModel.sort(2,Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.setSource(QUrl('main.qml'))

myApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = MainWindow()
ui.show()
sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

From Qml I called the slot sortData() .sortData() function is not correct i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To order the view the most appropriate option is to use QSortProxyModel but this will only work from the Python side, if we want to expose that method to QML we must make some modifications so create a class that inherits from QSortProxyModel and add that method:

```
class SortProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    @pyqtSlot(str, Qt.SortOrder)
    def sortData(self, roleName, order):
        if order == Qt.InitialSortOrderRole:
            self.setSortRole(order)
            self.invalidate()
        else:
            roles = [key for key, value in self.roleNames().items() if value == roleName.encode()]
            if len(roles) > 0:
                self.setSortRole(roles[0])
                self.sort(0, order)
```

Then what you have to do is pass as the base the original model through `setSourceModel()`, and this new model is what you must pass to qml.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    model = PersonModel()
    proxyModel = SortProxyModel()
    proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty('mymodel', proxyModel)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('main.qml')))
    if len(engine.rootObjects()) == 0:
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(myApp.exec_())
```

<sub>In the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/4f47e4f59100340b8328438a39011b31) there is an example</sub>

Comment: sorry@eyllanesc

Comment: Hello,                                                                                                                       I Need to access the data from the list model in qml.                                          
console.log(PersonModel.data(1,'value1'))                                                  is the function call I used. But Iam getting the result as 'undefind'. What's the wrong there?